How is liberation percentage contribution when you complete a mission calculated?
When you complete a mission in Helldivers 2, after it gives you your rewards, it'll tell you how much your mission helped the liberation percentage.
For example, I once got a 0.0001% liberation percentage contribution after a mission (it's low because me and my friends spent the whole time hunting each other instead of paying attention to objectives).
How is this liberation percentage contribution calculated?

All objectives in Helldivers are tweaked by Game Masters; as such, there isn't a hard and fast formula to everything.
However, it is currently known that:

Every objective has a goal number of points to be met.
Your difficulty has a multiplier which is added to the base contribution. (ie. doing objectives in an Easy run contributes less than an Expert run, even if both runs had exactly the same set or number of objectives)

